# PHP7 now throws Undefined Index exceptions. Can I disable this?

Tags: php, php-7, php-7.2

It appears that in php 56, which we're migrating away from, you could do this:

$_SERVER['someKeyThatDoesntExist']

And you would have null returned.

However, in php 72, which we are upgrading to, if you do that, you get...

0 /index.php(10): exception_error_handler(8, ‘Undefined index...‘, ‘/var/www/...’, 10, Array) #1 {main}

Is there a way to disable these exceptions from being thrown? I'm migrating a 100,000+ line code base to php72, and it would be awful to have to do exists checks all over the place to account for these new exceptions.

Comment: you could change the error_reporting level

Comment: I don't think error_reporting influence which exceptions are being thrown.

Comment: That's still [just an E_NOTICE](https://3v4l.org/GBkcj) in PHP 7.2.  It looks like you probably have a customised [error handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php).

Comment: @Evert It would if you're using a custom handler with [ErrorException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php)

Comment: Right, so OP should fix their error handler? It's better to fix this problem though, it's a bad practice

Comment: OP could either edit the handler or edit the set reporting level and use the logic in [this example](http://php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php#errorexception.examples)

Comment: Whoa! You're right! It's my custom error handler. I don't think I EVER would have figured that out. Thanks a ton, @salathe

Comment: You should also be checking for the existince of an array index before you try to use it. https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

Comment: null coalescing operator `$_SERVER['someKeyThatDoesntExist'] ?? null` http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php Refactoring should be done, just disabling errors is evil. A good IDE should aid doing this task. Regex search/replace over filesystem trees with confirmation. 10 minutes work in e.g. PhpStorm